# Actions broken in Xcode 9 project

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, xcode9, macos-high-sierra

OK, so here's the deal...

I'm trying to connect even the simplest actions (the typical <kbd>ctrl+drag</kbd> from the UI builder to the corresponding file), the actions are created fine, but they're not working.

**What the UI (with a test action) looks like:**

[image]

**And the corresponding part in `AppDelegate.swift`** (which doesn't get called no matter what)

[image]

---

In case it makes any difference:

- **macOS** : High Sierra 10.13.2
- **Xcode** : 9.1 (9B55)
- **Project platform** : macOS
- **Project language** : Swift
- **Storyboards** : NO
- **Auto Layout** : NO

---

Which files should I have a look into, in case something has been corrupted?

I have had a look into `MainMenu.xib` but the `<connection>` and `<action>`s there seem to be linking the correct things. Maybe it's the `project.pbxproj` file?

---

**Note:** The project in question is a result of (automatically) duplicating a previous Xcode (+Swift) project, so chances are something *might* have gone wrong during the process. (although it normally works for me). Let's see...

Comment: Probably irrelevant, but I presume you've done a full clean and rebuild?

Comment: @JohnParker yes, of course

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon close and reopen Xcode?

Comment: @BrianOgden Nope, unfortunately. Tried that too...

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon I would delete and add the Action outlet again

Comment: Have you tried cleaning DerivedData?

Answer (score 0):

The first and possibly only place to sanity check Outlets,Segues,Actions is this right panel menu in Xcode:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately all the actions (+ outlets) show fine. The code looks good. All of a sudden, it just doesn't get called. (Just updated my initial question)

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking that the @IBAction line for buttonClicked should be in the viewController file instead of the AppDelegate file